# How to combine `MAX` and `JOIN` to get correct output?

Tags: mysql

I have the select output :

```
SELECT 

t1.NO_PROJECT,
t1.ID_ACTIVITY,
t2.NO,
t2.NAMA_ACTIVITY,
t2.LEVEL_ACTIVITY

FROM t1

INNER JOIN t2
    ON t1.ID_ACTIVITY = t2.NO

ORDER BY LEVEL_ACTIVITY DESC

LIMIT 1
```

The result of this select query is:

```
NO_PROJECT   ID_ACTIVITY   NO   NAMA_ACTIVITY   LEVEL_ACTIVITY
PRJ-2017-544           2    2         03 DRTU                3
PRJ-2017-544           6    6      09 P.HARGA                9    
PRJ-2017-544           7    7          08 HPS                8
```

I use `ORDER BY LEVEL_ACTIVITY DESC` and `LIMIT 1` to get my desired output. But, how do I do it if I use `MAX(LEVEL_ACTIVITY)`?

the output should be (when I use `ORDER BY LEVEL_ACTIVITY DESC` and `LIMIT 1`) :

```
NO_PROJECT   ID_ACTIVITY   NO   NAMA_ACTIVITY   LEVEL_ACTIVITY    
PRJ-2017-544           6    6      09 P.HARGA                9
```

I'd like to know how do I get the same output when using `MAX(LEVEL_ACTIVITY)`

Comment: `LIMIT 1` means there should only be 1 row in the output. How are you getting 3 rows?

Comment: @Barmar I'd like to get the last activity based on LEVEL_ACTIVITY.

Comment: I don't see how you can be getting that output from the query you show. If you use `LIMIT 1`, it will only output one row, not 3 rows.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can join with a subquery to get `MAX(level_activity)`.

```
SELECT 
    t1.NO_PROJECT,
    t1.ID_ACTIVITY,
    t2.NO,
    t2.NAMA_ACTIVITY,
    t2.LEVEL_ACTIVITY
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 
    ON t1.ID_ACTIVITY = t2.NO
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(LEVEL_ACTIVITY) AS MAX_LA FROM t2) AS t3
    ON t2.LEVEL_ACTIVITY = t3.MAX_LA
```

If you do this, and there are multiple rows in `t2` with the highest `LEVEL_ACTIVITY`, they'll all be in the results. Or if there are multiple rows in `t1` that join with the highest level activity, they'll all be in the results.

If you only want 1 result, your original method should work. You can't get 3 rows as you show when you use `LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  t1.NO_PROJECT,
  t1.ID_ACTIVITY,
  t2.NO,
  t2.NAMA_ACTIVITY,
  t2.LEVEL_ACTIVITY,
  (SELECT MAX(LEVEL_ACTIVITY) AS MAX FROM t2)
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.ID_ACTIVITY = t2.NO
ORDER BY LEVEL_ACTIVITY DESC    
LIMIT 1`
```

Comment: Won't `MAX` be the same as `LEVEL_ACTIVITY` in this query?